# Area 51 sites api

Tags: discussion, api, area51

Why does http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/stackauth-methods/sites not list **Area 51** (http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because area51 doesn't have an API. It's not a traditional stack exchange site and runs differently.